# matrix searching word in python

Tags: python, string, matrix, search

I need to build a function that searches for words from a list within a matrix of letters,
If a word exists the function will return list of tupels with the words that in the matrix.  and in every tuple tere is a word and the number of times it appears in the matrix.(word,number)
I an stuck and i would like foe help.

```
def right(word_list, matrix):
    sum_lst = []
    one_word = [''.join(row) for row in matrix]
    for word in word_list:
        for string in one_word:
            print(string)
            count =string.count(word)
            if word in string:
                if (word,count) not in sum_lst:
                    sum_lst.append((word, count))



    return sum_lst
```

It brings me back to the fact that a word appears once even if it actually appears more than once.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you give example input plus desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It brings me back to the fact that a word appears once even if it actually appears more than once.
```

The posted code will grab word counts if the differ, e.g. the same word but different counts (say 1 and 2).

I think here what you mean is that the same word appears in multiple rows of the `matrix` then occurrence on each row counts as a `+1`.

If I run this example:

```
matrix =[['a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 
         ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 
         ['e', 'f', 'g'], 
         ['e', 'f', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'h']]

words = ['abba']
result = right(words, matrix)
result
```

with the code given in the post I see

```
>>> result
[('abba', 1), ('abba', 2)]
```

whereas what it sounds like you want is: `[('abba', 2)]`.

Here I'd keep a dictionary of the words and the frequency of their occurrence on rows and at the end convert into the list of tuples, assuming you need results in that format from question.

```
def right(words, matrix):
    word_occur = dict()
    one_word = [''.join(row) for row in matrix]
    for word in words:
        if word in one_word:
            word_occur[word] = word_occur.get(word,0) + 1
    return [item for item in word_occur.items()]
```

On the example I gave this gives

```
[('abba', 3)]
```

which counts the 1st, 2nd, and 4th row. For the example provided in a comment it gives:

```
[('app', 2), ('nner', 1)]
```

which sounds like what you want.

Comment: what i mean is that if word appears twice in the matrix , the function will return: [('word',2)], i dont know how to update the count evey single loop.

Comment: @yaeB is the `2` count the desired value if there are 2 occurrences of the word on first row and 1 occurrence on the second row (and no others)?

Comment: i think example would be the best way to explain myself :),input-['app','nner','god'],[['a','p','p','l','e'],['a','p','p','d','o'],['n','n','e','r','t'],['g','a','T','A','C']])                                                            output-[('app',2),('nner',1)] . The 2 count the desired value if there are 2 occurrences of the word in the whole matrix.

Comment: @yaeB I updated the answer to my current understanding of what is the desired output and matches your comment here.

Comment: thank you, its working. do you have some tips\ ways to make my code more elegant and shorter.

Comment: @yaeB IIUC that is really a question for a different site than Stack overflow, see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211790/854716 it sounds like that is a code review question. Plus to some extent elegance is in the eye of the beholder so not really a question with clear answer(s). FWIW the code I wrote looks fine to me :)

Comment: @yaeB I cleaned up the code that I wrote before, it is now a bit less and still giving same result. This is simpler and should be faster too.

Comment: Hi, it is not working, it prints an empty list every time no metter what the input is.